# Raspberry PI not booting Snappy Ubuntu Core

Tags: snappy

I just bought a Raspberry Pi B+ model and i am trying to load SNAPPY UBUNTU CORE using it. I have followed the instructions and wrote the ubuntu core into a 32gb SD Card. But it seems the Pi could not load it. All i could see is a rainbow colored screen and it is getting looped again and again. Please help!

For Reference, Please see the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnpZuP23OTY&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Ubuntu Snappy only works on a Raspberry Pi 2, not on a Raspberry Pi B+. See here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/snappy/
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is now 2017 and the Ubuntu core has an image for the Raspberry Pi 3.

https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Snappy Core on the B+; it is compiled for the ARMv7 Pi 2.  The B+ is ARMv6.

As far as I am aware, Ubuntu does not have any ARMv6 distributions.