# What compatibility is there between Legacy Pi and Pi 2?

Tags: ubuntu, pi-models

Basically, I have a legacy Pi and [Ubuntu MATE for RPi](http://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) says it's for RPi 2.

Will software designed for RPi 2 boot / run on legacy Pi? Are there big incompatibilities?

Comment: Probably not they are compiled for 2 different ARM chips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing we have to a previous version of this quesion is this:

[Raspberry PI not booting Snappy Ubuntu Core](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/30048/5538)

And the same logic applies to MATE. The reason there's a pile of distros for the Pi 2 is that most of the big names including Ubuntu already had ARMv7 versions, since ARMv7 is much more common beyond the pi than ARMv6. But those won't run on A/B/+ models.

Although some of them appear to be made just for the pi, this is probably not entirely true.  On the one hand, no matter what, a pi compatible distro does require a custom kernel.  On the other, compiling the kernel is only a tiny speck of a task in relation to the thousands of packages that make up a distro, all of which must be maintained over time and may need the equivalent of (several) full time hours to do.  For the big mainstream distros, this is spread out over a large number of packagers who are responsible only for a few packages each and can therefore probably take care of things in an occasional evening.  And/or they pay people ([related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124410/25985)).

I would guess that MATE is an elaborated version of [something like this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27545/5538);<sup>1</sup> most of the packages come straight from the pre-existing Ubuntu ARMv7 (which I think much of that may come straight from the pre-existing Debian).

---

<sup>1. There's a note there observing that after I wrote that someone in fact released a Fedora "Pi Remix" which has all the work done for you. This is what the original Raspbian was -- one volunteer who put together a precompiled pi kernel with an existing Debian ARMv6 distro. Most of the other brands don't have one; Debian supports a wider range of hardware out of the box than anyone else.</sup>

Comment: Okay, thanks! By the way, [I did try to see if this would be a dupe.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26706817#26706817)

Comment: I know, that's why I started this that way ;)