# Is Ubuntu Snappy compatible with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: snappy

I have the new Raspberry Pi 3 and trying to run Snappy on it. I know that there is a 100% compatibility between 2 and 3 but Sanppy fails to boot on 3 (rainbow screen no IO light flashing).

Has anyone tried running Snappy on 3?

Comment: could be the SD card maybe, does it work in a pi2 (if you have one)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own a Pi 2. Could it be the CPU Arch difference (A7 vs A53)?

Comment: just a fyi. I got a Raspberry Pi 3 and gave it a tried it last night. It doesn't work. I was able to get Ubuntu MATE to work on Pi3 as an interim solution while I wait for the Snappy Ubuntu Core, but it was 8GB big.

Comment: update 05/16/2016 it doesnt work, ive just testet it.
dd'd the image via rufus and win32 disk imager,
both times stuck in rainbow screen like the author said.
looks like the kernel image is missing, but i have no clue.
im going to try ubuntu mate 16.04 now,
i would rather use snappy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry PI not booting Snappy Ubuntu Core](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/raspberry-pi-not-booting-snappy-ubuntu-core)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of this time, the rpi3 is not supported by Snappy. Canonical engineers got the device at the same time as everyone else (and it's in demand!), and this takes some time. Currently only the rpi2 is supported (among other non-rp devices, of course).

**Update as of 05/13/16**: The rpi3 can actually run the rpi2 image now, but it's still 32-bit. Progress is being made on enabling 64-bit, but rpi didn't make that very easy.

**Update as of 10/27/16**: The rpi3 is officially supported along with the rpi2. Ubuntu Core 16 has reached release candidate, and [images are available](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/16.04/current/) for all supported platforms.

Note that the rpi3 image is still 32-bit, though progress is being made on a 64-bit image.

Comment: Is this still true ?!

Comment: Thanks for asking-- I updated the answer with a small update :) .

Comment: May I suggest that you provide a link to where this progress can be observed? This way people don't have to ask every month whether it's supported or not.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such link. The best I can offer is the #snappy channel on freenode.

Comment: I just updated the answer to indicate that the rpi3 is now an officially supported device for Ubuntu Core.